# How to create standalone WSDL based web service using Spring WS?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

Please, help me to run standalone web service on local machine using Spring WS and existing wsdl. 
I am new in Spring WS. There is my code:
package com.mayacomp.ws;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

web service end point:

```
package com.mayacomp.endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import com.mayacomp.pack.intRequest;
import com.mayacomp.pack.IntResponse;


@Endpoint
public class WsEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://new.webservice.namespace";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "intRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public IntResponse getIntHist(@RequestPayload intRequest request) {
        try {
com.mayacomp.pack.IntResponse _return = new com.mayacomp.pack.IntResponse();
        /*a lot of setters for _return object*/
            return _return;
        } catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

and webservie config:

```
package com.mayacomp.ws;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.Wsdl11Definition;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
      @Bean
      public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
      }

      @Bean(name = "MayaService")
      public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("MayaService.wsdl"));
        return wsdl11Definition;
      }
}
```

my pom file looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <artifactId>maya-ws</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- tag::springws[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- end::springws[] -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I need to run application (I can run) and get web service via link like localhost:8080/ws/MayaService?wsdl 
I will be glad for any advices.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: The problem is unvailable http://localhost:8080/ws/MayaService?wsdl from SOUP UI. If generally - absence of experience in spring/spring ws.

Comment: Also one side of problem is that all examples are based on xsd and most of them are war packaging.

Comment: By the way i can open link localhost:8080/ws/MayaService.wsdl (with dot). But when i try to execute any operation from wsdl in soup ui i am redirected to link like  www.mayacomp.com and i receive in response strange html code from page (not xml response).